# How to add logistic term to numeric series?

Tags: sequences-and-series, logistic-regression

I have found a formula to calculate the number of items y after a certain value x (e.g. time) given the size of items at the beginning of the series:
$$
    y_x = a^x y_0
$$
I would like to convert it to include a logistic term `1-x/k` and I know that:
$$
    y_{x+1} = a^2 y_ x \left(1-\frac{y_x}{k} \right)
$$
and
$$
    y_{x+1} = y_x \exp \left[a(1-\frac{y_x}{k}) \right]
$$
How can I convert `yₓ₊₁ ∝ yₓ` to `yₓ ∝ y₀` including the logistic term?

How can I solve for $y_0$?

Thank you

Comment: If $y_x = a^x y_0$  then (a) $y_{x+1}=a y_x$,  and (b) this is exponential, not logistic, and (c) if $a > 1$ then it faces unbounded growth while if $0 < a < 1$ then it faces exponential decay

Comment: Thank you, but it is possible to convert the last equation into a y₀-equivalent? (I have no background in math so I am a little navigating in the dark...)